# Finding the zeros/poles of a function

Tags: roots, laplace-transform

My textbook has the following function and states that this function has poles at $0, −1, −2, ∞$:

$$
G(s)=\dfrac{e^{-2s}}{10s(s+1)(s+2)}
$$

I understand where the $0,-1$ and $-2$ are coming from but where is the infinity coming from also shouldn't there be zeros at $∞$ as well?

Can someone please help explain this?

Please feel free to edit the tags, thank you.

Comment: I think the textbook may be indicate that the function tends to `0` where `s` tends to $\infty$.

Comment: That's wrong. That function has an essential singularity at $\infty$, not a pole.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, so there is suppose to be a zero at infinity and only poles at 0,-1,-2?

Comment: typo?  i.e. $-\infty$?

Comment: @BadAtMath, so there would be a pole at 0,-1,-2 and −∞? And zeros of order 4 at ∞?

Comment: I don't think it's a pole at $\infty$ or $-\infty$.  The only poles are 0, -1, -2.

Comment: @BadAtMath, can there be a zero at ∞ or −∞?

Comment: I'm assuming there's a 0 at infinity is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

To long for a comment.

Considering only the zeros of

$$
G(s) = e^{-2s}
$$

making $s = x + i y$ and substituting we have that $G(s)=0$ can be written as

$$
\cases{
e^{-2x}\cos(2y) = 0\\
e^{-2x}\sin(2y) = 0
}
$$

so we have an **improper** zero as $x\to\infty$